# Table created by lambda function is not visible in dynamodb. Using loclstack for testing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

I have created a lambda function which will create a table in dynamodb.
I am using localstack.The problem is that table is getting created but not visible in dynamodb when using command aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:4566

my lambda function code:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', aws_access_key_id='',aws_secret_access_key='',endpoint_url="http://<ip address>:4566")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
   


    movie_table = dynamodb.create_table(
        TableName='Movies',
        KeySchema=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'year',
                'KeyType': 'HASH'  # Partition key
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'title',
                'KeyType': 'RANGE'  # Sort key
            }
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {
                'AttributeName': 'year',
                'AttributeType': 'N'
            },
            {
                'AttributeName': 'title',
                'AttributeType': 'S'
            },

        ],
        ProvisionedThroughput={
            'ReadCapacityUnits': 10,
            'WriteCapacityUnits': 10
        }
    )
    print("Table status:", movie_table.table_status)
```

Also getting EndpointConnectionError if giving value of endpoint-url= http://localhost:4566

template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Description: >
  AWS

  Sample SAM Template for AWS

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 60



Resources:

  AddItem:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: dynamodbAddItem/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.7
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the DynamoDB service is running inside of localstack (using docker), `SERVICES=...` has to include `dynamodb`
2. Specifically for accessing localstack inside of a lambda function documentation says this:

> Use this hostname as endpoint (e.g.,
> http://${LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME}:4566) in order to access the services
> from within your Lambda functions (e.g., to store an item to DynamoDB
> or S3 from a Lambda).

Are you able to interact with DynamoDB by e.g. a simple `aws --endpoint <localstack-addr> dynamodb list-tables`?

Comment: Yes I am able to interact to dynamodb but table is not visible when I try to interact with dynamodb throgh lambda. Although lmbda is able to create table nd insert data when it is not visible when I run aws --endpoint <localstack-addr> dynamodb list-tables

Comment: @ShobhnaDhami does your lambda also have error handling for the table creation command? The lambda run can be succesful without actually having executed the command properly. Perhaps you can give [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-1.html) a try to check if the 'Music' table will be listed. In that case DynamoDB should function correctly.

Comment: @Sjoukdev I tried it and yes the table is listed when I am using cli but when table is created through code it is not visible in the table list.

Comment: Okay, that's strange. I guess your last resort is creating an issue on github